# Why is the targetNamespace ignored if the element is not defined at the global level?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

Here is the *schema.xsd*.
It defines a `targetNamespace` `ns` where element `'A'` includes element `'B'`.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ns">
    <xsd:element name="root"/>

    <xsd:element name="A">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="B" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Here is the *doc.xml*. 
It has an `'A'` node that includes a `'B'` node.
This xml is valid according to the schema.

```
<root 
    xmlns="ns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="ns schema.xsd" >

    <A xmlns="ns">
        <B xmlns=""/>
    </A>

</root>
```

This sounds all Ok ... except that `'B'` is not in namespace `ns`!

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms256460%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `'B'` should be in namespace `ns`.

> The targetNamespace is the namespace of **all** schema **components** in this
>   schema as well as any schemas included using the include element

Where is the problem: in my understanding or in the definition of `targetNamespace`?
.

Answer (score 0):

*B* is *not* in the namespace *ns* because it redeclares a new default namespace: the null namespace. In your example `root` and `A` are in the `ns` namespace. The `xmlns` declaration in `A` is not necessary, since it inherits the namespace from `root`.

In this example, `A`, `B` and `root` are all in the `ns` namespace:

```
<root xmlns="ns"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="ns schema.xsd" >

    <A>
        <B/>
    </A>
</root>
```

In this other example, `B` and `root` are in the `ns` namespace, but `A` is in the *null* namespace:

```
<root xmlns="ns"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="ns schema.xsd" >

    <A xmlns="">
        <B xmlns="ns"/>
    </A>
</root>
```